# Put the result of simple tag into a variable

Tags: python, django, django-templates, templatetag

this works:

```
{% get_option 'payment_conditions' '' true %}
```

It calls a function with 3 parameters and it returns a string: "I am the conditions". Great.

What I want to do now is to put this in a IF statement. So to do this, I need the value into a variable. Something like:

```
{% with conditions = get_option 'payment_conditions' '' true %}
```

But it does not work. I also tried:

```
{% get_option 'payment_conditions' '' true as conditions %}
```

Is there a way that I can place the result into a variable??
Thanks

Comment: Is `get_option` a template tag you defined?

Comment: yes, it is defined and it works out of the IF statement.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Please use assignment tag if you are using django < 1.9. The doc is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#assignment-tags). I posted the example in the docs here:

```
@register.assignment_tag
def get_current_time(format_string):
    return datetime.datetime.now().strftime(format_string)
```

Then in template:

```
{% get_current_time "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p" as the_time %}
<p>The time is {{ the_time }}.</p>
```

You can see that the template tag result becomes a variable using `as` statement. You can use `the_time` however you like, including `if` statement.

Also quote from the docs:

> Deprecated since version 1.9: simple_tag can now store results in a
>   template variable and should be used instead.

Comment: `assignment_tag` has been removed in Django 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Since Django >=2.0, please use `simple_tag`:

```
@register.simple_tag
def get_current_time(currency):
    return datetime.datetime.now().strftime(format_string)
```

Then in the template:

```
{% get_current_time "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p" as the_time %}
<p>The time is {{ the_time }}.</p>
```