# Django: Use firstof of if-else block inside blocktrans

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have two variables **var1** and **var2**. I want to do this,

```
{% blocktrans %}
    value of my var is: {% firstof var1 var2 %}
{% endblocktrans%}
```

It gives me error that **'blocktrans' doesn't allow other block tags**. Because we are not allowed to use any other tag inside blocktrans, what is the solution of this kind of problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From django 1.9 onwards, you can use `firstof` to assign result to context.

```
{% firstof var1 var2 as myvar %}

{% blocktrans %}
    value of my var is: {{ myvar }}
{% endblocktrans%}
```

See [django-docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#firstof) and [issue tracker](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12199) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I can't use the partner's answer because I use **django version < 1.9**, for me the solution was the one found in the following link (don't forget to like Shang Wang if it worked for you): [Put the result of simple tag into a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32182116/put-the-result-of-simple-tag-into-a-variable)

As our friend Shang says, you must create a method with the assignment_tag decorator, this way we can save the response in a method and consume it from the template:

```
@register.assignment_tag(takes_context=True)
def precio_format_with_locale_assignment(context, cantidad):
    locale = context.dicts[1]["locale"]
    reserva = context.dicts[1]["reserva"]
    return format_price_with_locale(reserva, cantidad, locale)
```

As you can see I added (takes_context=True) to access to the context as in a simple_tag.

And to use it in the template:

```
{% precio_format_with_locale_assignment interval.amount as interval_amount %}

{% blocktrans with date=interval.date trimmed %}
     Desde el {{ date }}: se cobrarán {{ interval_amount }}.
{% endblocktrans %}
```